Green's Representation Formula for Biregular Functions
The text I'm following (about electromagnetism) seems to use the following fact:
Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open bounded connected set where Gauss' lemma holds, then every function $v \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C^1(\bar{\Omega})$ can be written as
\begin{equation}
v(x)= \int_{\partial \Omega} (\Phi(y-x) \frac{\partial v}{\partial n}(y) - v(y) \frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial n}(y-x)) dS(y) - \int_{\Omega} \Phi(y-x) \Delta v(y) dy
\end{equation}
For $x \in \Omega$, and where $n$ is the normal outward to the surface, and $\Phi$ is the fundamental solution to Laplace's equation.
I know this formula for normal domains where $v \in C^2(\bar{\Omega})$, but I don't know how to prove this.
